# Send an email with a excel file that includes a macro

Tags: excel, vba

I created an excel file where I added some buttons that I connected to different macros. I want to send this excel file to a collegue but when he opens this file the button gives an error:

> Cannot run the macro "macro-name". The macro may not be available in this workbook or all macros may be disabled.

Is there a way to include or insert macro's inside the excel file?

[I use Microsoft Office Professional Plus 2010]

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer myself, sorry:

Save as.. "Excel Macro-Enabled Workbook (*.xlsm)

Comment: You may find that in order for others to run your code, you might need a code signing certificate.  Basically, it tells other people's Excel that you are trusted and your code has not been tampered.